# How can I confirm whether the in-app purchase actually worked on a Test iTunes Connect user?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've setup an iTunes Connect test user and was able to perform an in-app purchase, partly with this guide: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/

According to the code, the transaction was completed. But I would like to be sure, so I had thought that maybe my test account's email address received a message confirming the transaction. There is no such message, perhaps because it was a sandbox mode purchase.

Is there another way I can confirm that the test purchase was actually processed by Apple's test servers, in case that my code is bugged and is giving me the wrong signals? I took a look at my iTunes Connect page, but there doesn't seem to be a view with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary source of information here comes from the SKPaymentTransactionObserver protocol:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
```

when you receive a transaction back with `transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` then you know everything between Apple and your customer worked out great.

Your code doesn't call this method directly, and unless you have done some serious (and not approved by apple) tinkering around in the private API's, you can trust that messages you receive here came from Apple, and are legit. Having pushed a few $billion through the appStore, you can bet they've worked out the bugs in this code from their side too.

You will not receive any e-mail confirmation for sandbox test accounts. All you can do is handle the delegate methods appropriately and move on.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the **SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased** status means transaction successfully completed.

In Sandbox mode apple doesn't send any email to anyone but yes when you do this in Live(Production) environment then Apple does send an email with Purchased product details.